# I can not make the label vary interactively

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I want to make a label vary when I click on a button. But when I click, nothing happens.

I tried using the textvariable, normal text, .config method. but nothing seems to be working

```
from tkinter import *

global Forca
Forca = 0

def ad_for():
    global Forca
    Forca += 1
    show_forca['text'] = Forca

def hp():
    global vida
    vida = Forca + 10
    show_ferimentos['text'] = vida

ficha = Tk()
caracteristicas = Frame()
caracteristicas.grid(row=1,column=0)

forca = Label(caracteristicas, text='FORÇA FÍSICA')
forca.grid(row=0,column=0)
show_forca = Label(caracteristicas,text='-')
show_forca.grid(row=0,column=1)
b_forca = Button(caracteristicas,text='+',command=ad_for)
b_forca.grid(row=0,column=2)

recursos = Frame()
recursos.grid(row=1,column=1)
ferimentos = Label(recursos,text='FERIMENTOS')
ferimentos.grid(row=0,column=0)
show_ferimentos = Label(recursos,text=hp)
show_ferimentos.grid(row=0,column=1)

ficha.mainloop()
```

I hope that by clicking the `b_forca` button, you can interactively modify the label `show_ferimentos`

Comment: The code you gave above works for me...

Comment: your button runs `ad_for` , not `hp`  - so you run wrong function.

Comment: yes, but clicking the ```ad_for``` button will add 1, and it should also be added to the label ```show_ferimentos```

Comment: I managed to find a way to do what I wanted. Thank you